# Происхождение выражения "... - не хочу"

Tags: этимология

К примеру "Ешь - не хочу"; в значении "в избытке, достаточно". (Как вариация, "Ешь душа - не хочу".)
Интересно, известны ли ранние версии данного выражения, и существовали ли они?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что тут имеется в виду, что можно есть до тех пор, пока не перестанешь хотеть. А вот на счет ранних версий, честно говоря, не слышала.